# Design patterns for "first run" messaging?

Tags: messages, dialog, first-impression

I'm working on a major re-design of a web app, and I'm contemplating popping up a "Welcome to the New Site!" dialog when users first log in to it. I can't seem to find too much discussion of those things online. Anyone have any pointers to patterns or best practices?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I would display an unobtrusive notification bar which slides from the top of the webpage, welcoming users to your new website, which can be closed when clicked.

Take a look at [**this example**](http://needim.github.com/noty/) of the notification message (in the "Top" box, click on the "Information" button for example). As you can see on the page, there are also a lot of options for customizing this particular script to suit your needs. Good luck!